# Pass Image data to PHP with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm trying to make a form to upload images to a database and folder in the server. I'm having trouble figuring out how to send the image data over to the PHP file with javascript.

I have the following Javascript:

```
function FeedPost() {
    $('#FeedResults').show();
    document.getElementById('FeedResults').innerHTML = '<center><img src="img/Loading.gif" title="Loading" /></center>';    
    var post_text = document.getElementById('PostText').value;
    var file = document.getElementById('PostImage').files[0];
    var file_name = file.name;
    var file_size = file.size;
    var file_type = file.type;
    var dataString = 'feed='+post_text+'&img_name='+file_name+'&img_size='+file_size+'&img_type='+file_type;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "post_feed.php?"+dataString,
        dataType: "json",   
        success: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            var entry = data[i]; 
            var success = entry.results.success;
            var message = entry.results.message;
        }
        document.getElementById('FeedResults').innerHTML = '<div class="ResultsText">'+message+'</div>';
    }
 });        
}
```

In the PHP I removed the $_FILE[] coding to make sure that the file variables were going through in the PHP, which they are.

here's the PHP Code:

```
<?php
$feed_message = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['feed']));
$img_name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['img_name']));
$img_size = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['img_size']));
$img_type = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['img_type']));
$folder="img/uploads/";
// new file size in KB
$new_size = $img_size/1024;  
// new file size in KB

// make file name in lower case
$new_file_name = strtolower($img_name);
// make file name in lower case 
$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

$img_output = $final_file.''.$img_type;
// Checking post Variables
if($img_size == 0) {
    if(strlen($feed_message) < 3) {
        $message = 'Post Too Short';
        $results = ['success' => false, 'message' => $message];
    }
    else {
        $message = 'Post Successful!';
        $results = ['success' => true, 'message' => $message];
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed(user,message,img,time) values ('$id','$feed_message','NULL','".time()."')");
    }
}
// Post has an image attached
else {
    if(strlen($feed_message) < 3) {
        $message = 'Post Too Short';
        $results = ['success' => false, 'message' => $message];
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($final_file,$folder);
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed (user,message,img) values ('$id','$feed_message','$img_output','".time()."')");
        $message = 'Image Posted!';
        $results = ['success' => true, 'message' => $message];
    }
}
$data[] = ['results' => $results];
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The output url is: post_feed.php?feed=Testing....&img_name=Wiz-Khalifa.jpg&img_size=271330&img_type=image/jpeg

And the PHP output is as following: [{"results":{"success":true,"message":"Image Posted!"}}]

Added HTML:

```
           <form action="javascript:void;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" id="PostText" placeholder="Message" />
                <input type="file" name="file" id="PostImage" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="LoginButton" onClick="FeedPost()" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="LoginButton" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @Glide  Thanks for helping me with the issue. I already knew that, I would love to learn the functioning of MySQLi, but I work full time and don't have the available time to do so.

Comment: use the tmp_name instead of the img_name when uploading it

Comment: send the entire form when you are uploading file

Comment: @NewbeeDev  How can I do that exactly with javascript?

Comment: could you provide your html

Comment: @NewbeeDev Yeah I'll update the question with the HTML

Comment: @NewbeeDev Added it

Comment: @NewbeeDev It's there now. Originally added the wrong HTML

Answer (score 0):

just add this into your js file

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file); // append file to your form


// add this to your ajax request parameters to pass the image file
data: formData, // add this to your parameters in your ajax request
```

your js will be like this

```
function FeedPost() {
    $('#FeedResults').show();
    document.getElementById('FeedResults').innerHTML = '<center><img src="img/Loading.gif" title="Loading" /></center>';    
    var post_text = document.getElementById('PostText').value;
    var file = document.getElementById('PostImage').files[0];


    // you just add this
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file); // append file to your form


    var file_name = file.name;
    var file_size = file.size;
    var file_type = file.type;
    var dataString = 'feed='+post_text+'&img_name='+file_name+'&img_size='+file_size+'&img_type='+file_type;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "post_feed.php?"+dataString,
        data: formData, // add this to your parameters in your ajax request
        dataType: "json",   
        success: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            var entry = data[i]; 
            var success = entry.results.success;
            var message = entry.results.message;
        }
        document.getElementById('FeedResults').innerHTML = '<div class="ResultsText">'+message+'</div>';
    }
 });        
}
```

In your php file

Change your

```
move_uploaded_file($final_file,$folder);
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $folder.'/' . $final_file);
```

Comment: just tell me if you have any errors if you have try to var_dump($_FILES); inyour php file to debug the file

Comment: Hey, I got this error code: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: try replacing data: formData to data: new FormData($("form")[0]) and remove var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file); // append file to your form

Comment: Could you start a conversation on here with me

Comment: create a room for this post

Comment: I apparently don't have enough Rep to do so

Comment: have you tried changing it to data: new FormData($("form")[0])

Comment: Yeah, Try the room now, I'm in

Comment: give me the link of the room

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124363/pass-image-data-to-php-with-javascript-solution

Answer (score 0):

I was testing the solution for you. It's tested the connection via ajax to the post_feed.php, it's saving the file and making the validation necessary to the variables in the server side.

The only thing I didn't test was the mysql_query function -I mean, actually prove that it's saving the image to the database, only let the query with the modified variables. Comment the lines $is_postInsertedWithImage = true and $is_postInsertedWithoutImage = true to the real mysql_query once you tested that the connection via ajax actually work and also that the file is being saved img/uploads/ folder .

I organize a litte bit the code. The javascript is connectin via AJAX to the php file successfully, uploading in the folder the image and giving the response back to the index.html.

One thing, please read the comments I let you in the code, because there are things that I comment to better understand like remember to check the folder permissions where you going to upload and also call your attention to some details like the variable $id that you use in your mysql_query and  was not showing up in your code, and it will be necesary to test the query, which I let you a $userId = 4 as a way you can test or uncomment the part to access it via session. I hope it helps you. happy code!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     function FeedPost() {

      var element = document.getElementById('FeedResults');

      element.innerHTML += '<center><img src="img/Loading.gif" title="Loading" /></center>';    

      var post = document.getElementById('postText').value;
      var file = document.getElementById("postImage").files[0];      

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var formdata = new FormData();


      if(file !== undefined){
       formdata.append("file1", file);         
       } 
      formdata.append("post", post);   


      xhr.open("POST", "post_feed.php");
      xhr.send(formdata); 

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){

     eval("var response = (" + this.responseText + ")");
     
     // Check out the message response from the upload in the Browser Console 
     // before test the database. It should work fine. 
      console.log(response.message);      
     

      // element.innerHTML += response.message;
      // document.body.appendChild(element);
      alert(response.message);
    }
   }       
  }     
    </script>
```

```html
<?php

//Get the post feed
$postFeed = $_POST['post'];

//Lets check the post if is not ok we send a response and save memory
//there is no need to store any other variable or chech the image
if (strlen($postFeed) < 3) {
    
    $jsonMessage = json_encode(array(
        'message' => 'Your post is too short! It MUST have more than 3 characters'
    ));
    
    echo $jsonMessage;
    // Run out 
    exit();
}

// Where is your user ID stored?? I didn't see in the example
// session?? Cookie? Get it here in the PHP file not in the index.html Remember that!.
// For security reasons. Don't use global too.
// I just put a fixed value, 4, to the id to test purposes;

// example: session_start();
//$userId = $_SESSION['current_user_id']
$userId = 4;

//Get the file name
$fileName = $_FILES['file1']['name'];

//Get the size of the file to verification
$fileSize = $_FILES['file1']['size'];

//Get the type of file : image
$fileType = $_FILES['file1']['type'];

//Store errors in the file
$fileErrMsg = $_FILES['file1']['error'];

//Temporary file
$fileTmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

//Raises a flag if an error is found when uploading or with the image
$error_flag = 0;


//Path to upload the file. 
//My /img/ folder is placed where my php script runs
//Change to your folder
//IMPORTANT: Give file permission to write, ex: sudo chmod 777 /img/uploads or better use chmod go+w /img/uploads/ 

// change to your folder:
// $pathToUpload = dirname(__FILE__)."/img/uploads/";
$pathToUpload = dirname(__FILE__) . "/img/";

// The name of the file to Upload cleaned
$cleanFileNameToUpload = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($fileName));

// Store the message we want to use in the Ajax Call
$responseMessage = array();

//Check if it was uploaded an image use isset()
if (isset($fileName)) {
    if (!$fileTmp || $fileErrMsg > 0) {
        $responseMessage[] = 'An error ocurred when uploading!';
        $error_flag        = 1;
        
    } elseif ($fileSize > 500000) {
        
        $responseMessage[] = 'File is bigger than 500kb!';
        $error_flag        = 1;
        
    } else {
        
        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $pathToUpload . $fileName)) {
            $responseMessage['message'] = 'Yeah Babe! File Upload now let just save to database and we are done!';
            
            // Now we store in the database
            // in future try to learn mysqli or even Oriented Object aproach like PDO - it's really worth and also best practices - it's really easy to learn.    
            
            // For test - replace for the line below to test save the database.
            $is_postInsertedWithImage = true;
            
            //$is_postInsertedWithImage = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed (user,message,img) values ('$userId','$postFeed','$cleanFileNameToUpload','".time()."')");
            
            if ($is_postInsertedWithImage) {
                $responseMessage['message'] = 'Post with image inserted correctly!';
            } else {
                $responseMessage['message'] = 'There was an error saving the post in the database!';
            }
            
        } else {
            $responseMessage['message'] = 'It was not posible to write image in the folder. Check Permissions and Upload folder location!';
        }
    }
    
} else {
    // If there is no image save only the image 
    $is_postInserted = true;
    
    // $is_postInserted = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed(user,message,img,time) values ('$userId','$postFeed','NULL','".time()."')"); 
    
    if ($is_postInserted) {
        $responseMessage['message'] = 'Post without image inserted correctly!';
    } else {
        $responseMessage['message'] = 'There was an error saving the post without image in the database!';
    }
}

$jsonMessage = json_encode($responseMessage);
echo $jsonMessage; 
?>
```